# how to handle service in multithread

Tags: android, android-service

I have a services can be called by other activities and threads and some receivers wait for the callback from it. I know that a service is only one instance in my app. 
I want to run the service when it needs to be called, not all the time hanging on in the background. How can I start/stop the service safely? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Its very much like your needs. It starts when you want it to be...and stop when it got done its tasks automatically. So frees its memory immediately. Another big advantage is that it runs in its own thread, hence your main thread/UI will never halt.

If you decide that this answers your question, please mark it as "accepted". This will raise both your and my reputation score.

Comment: It looks it can be a good idea. I never used IntentService yet, but I think that it matches what I want. I am going to have a try this as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure...this is very useful and efficient for simple tasks that don't have need to bind with other components...

Answer (score 2):

MainPage.java

```
package com.pack.service_tost_handler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainPage extends Activity {
    static Mhandler  mhandler;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        mhandler=new Mhandler();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainPage.this, ServicePage.class);
        Log.i("log", "i m create in main page");
        startService(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_page, menu);

        return true;
    }

    class Mhandler extends Handler
    {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            if(msg.what==111)
            {

                Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, "welcome to "+ msg.obj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

ServicePage.java

```
package com.pack.service_tost_handler;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class ServicePage extends Service implements Runnable
{
    String[] ary;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        Log.i("log", "create");
        super.onCreate();
        ary= new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<ary.length;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait(5000);    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("log", "Exception");
            }
            Message msg= MainPage.mhandler.obtainMessage(111);
            msg.obj=ary[i];
            MainPage.mhandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }





}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. You tell me Service + Handler can be another combination. I will try this way.